# Save django summer note as typing

Tags: django, summernote

I currently have a working install of [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote).  What I am wondering, is does django offer the ability to have an event trigger when typing into the editor to save the post?

Comment: Do you mean in the admin panel or on your client facing pages?

Comment: @dacx I believe I found what I needed with this, but now am unsure how to set up the callback https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/169#issuecomment-200575618

Comment: This snippet does save the contents every 5 seconds in the browser's localStorage and on init loads them from there and adds it to the input field. Is that what you want? Or add it to your database?

Comment: @dacx database would be preffered as I am unsure that persists on browser reload

Comment: @dacx and I meant in the admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement [django-autosave](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-autosave) into the admin forum which does what I needed. The general gist is they have a Javascript file that uses query to store it in local storage, but also periodically sends it to the server. In case more than one person editing at once.